# Cannot open connection/ file when Using RCurl's scp function

Tags: r, scp, rcurl

I'm trying to pull a file from a remote server into my R session.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
library(RCurl)
x = "/mypath/thefile.txt"


y = read.fwf(scp(host = 'myhost.place', path = x, 
          user= "myusername", password = "mypass", binary = FALSE), 
          widths = c(-1, 9, -42, 4), colClasses = c("character", "character"),
          col.names = c("Var1", "Var2"))
```

And here is the error message I receive:

Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") : 
cannot open file '
followed by a bunch of numbers that appear to belong to the file I am attempting to read.

I've successfully used similar methods to read from the same server. For example, this code works fine:

```
a = "/myotherpath/someSASfile.sas7bdat"

b = read_sas(scp(host = 'myhost.place', path = a, 
          user= "myusername", password = "mypass", binary = TRUE))
```

Does anybody have any ideas as to why the second set of code works, but the first does not?

Comment: Files have different types. Function called is different.

Comment: The issue is that `scp` returns the content of remote file while the first arg `read.fwf` is a filename. Save the read file and then use the filename in read.fwf . That read_sas function seems to accept raw character streams and therefore working directly with the data

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the comments. They've helped me find a solution: readr's read_fwf function. 
Here's a link to CRAN's readr pdf:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/readr/readr.pdf

The read_fwf function works similarly to read.fwf, but it works better with reading large data, and swapping these functions has let me read the file successfully.

```
h = scp(host = 'myhost.place', path = x, 
    user= "myusername", password = "mypass", binary = FALSE)

i = read_fwf(h, fwf_positions(c(2, 53), c(11, 56), c("Var1", "Var2")))
```